# C++:difference between assigning a value to an object and a class

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
 int a;
  A() {a=0;}
  A(int b) {a=b+1;}
};
class B{
public:
   A a;
   B():a(0) {}


};

int main(void) {
    B *b = new B();
    cout<<b->a.a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I replaced `B():a(0) {}` by `B() {A(0)}` and output changed from 1 to 0. I am wondering what's the difference between them?

Comment: Didn't you ask (almost) the same question a few hours ago?

Comment: yeah. But I;m not confused by ":" so it is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3):

`B() : a(0) {}` explicitly initializes the member `B::a` with the value `0`. This is an example of a [member initializer list](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/8-5a-constructor-member-initializer-lists/). Basically, `a(0)` in this context calls `a`'s constructor with the argument `0`, which calls `A::A(int)`, which, by your implementation, adds `1` to the argument and assigns the result to `A::a`. Thus in the first case, `b->a.a == 1`.

On the other hand, `B() {A(0);}` default-initializes `B::a` (because `A` has a default constructor) and creates a nameless local temporary object `A(0);` which is destroyed immediately without changing anything. It is functionally equivalent to `B(){}`, which is does nothing at all. You can omit this trivial constructor because the compiler can implicitly generate it for you. See [special member functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions) for more information on how this works and under what conditions. Thus in the second case, you are calling the default constructor, which sets `b->a.a == 0`.